# Angular component not created correct after routing to it

Tags: angular, routes, components, stripe-payments

My problem is the following. My angular web-application must allow to perform payments. To do so, I have implemented Stripe as payment platform, and on mobile version I want to be able to perform payments using Google Pay and Apple Pay. At the moment I'm currently working on the Google Pay option. According to Stripe Documentation it is possible to do so using the [Payment Request Button](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/payment-request-button#using-your-own-button).

I have implemented the button and I am able to perform the payment and can see the payment in my backend. However, after the payment is processed I want to move to a checkout page. That's why when I receive the response I perform a `router.navigate`

```
.doPayment(params)
  .subscribe(responseIsOk => {
     if (responseIsOk as SellResult) {
       console.log('payment correctly performed');
       this.router.navigate(['./pages/checkout']);
     }
   });
```

I have also implemented the normal stripe payment method, which will use the [Stripe Card Elements](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/quickstart). I can then, pay using the two methods. Both of them will call the previous code snippet, which will redirect to the checkout page.

If I use the normal payment method, everything works fine, but if I use the google pay method, the payment page does not disappear (I see the checkout page component and below that the payment page component). I set some breakpoints in the ngOnInit method of the checkout component and when I pay with Google pay, it does not stop there.

Any clue what can be happenning?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

```
export const routes: Routes = [
 {
path: 'pages',
component: PagesComponent,
children: [
  {path: 'pay', canActivate: [AdminGuard], canDeactivate: [NavigationGuard],
    loadChildren: 'app/pages/pay/pay.module#PayModule'},
  {path: 'checkout', canActivate: [AdminGuard], loadChildren: 'app/pages/checkout/checkout.module#CheckoutModule'},
    ],
  },
];
```

Don't worry for the guards, it is passing them since in case it wasn't I would note that in the logs.

Comment: Have you tried `this.router.navigateByUrl('./pages/checkout')` ? Can you also please share your routing module?

Comment: I have not tried that, I just think it should work anyway since it works for one case it should work for the other. I edit with my routing module

Comment: Check if both responses are well managed - what you receive from Google pay is probably different from the other method.

Comment: I'm not receiving anything from google pay since it is integrated with Stripe it is Stripe that is giving my token back to perform the payment. I guess this may be due to the fact that I have to close a Google Pay listener or something. The token response from stripe is well managed, maybe I have to manage another one that I'm missing